# Does sql search faster if data is stored in a sorted order

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, database-design, indexing

I am creating a chat service which will be using a LAMP stack. It will be a REST api and it will store every chat message in its database.

I have a message table that contains :

id|content|timestamp

now, the api may require to get messages from a particular id between two timestamps.

As the timestamp is automatically added by mySQL , one can expect the timestamp column to be sorted (correct me on this if I am wrong).

I do not want create an index on the timestamp because there are going to be a fairly large number of write operations on that table, and also, the table will be a fairly large one.

I would like to know if searching in a sorted column is faster than just plain searching.

I want to prevent a full table scan just to get all the messages between two timestamps.

Comment: "messages from a particular id between two timestamps" -- The composite `INDEX(particular_id, timestamp)` will be optimal, and `PARTITIONing` will not help.

Comment: As i have mentioned , the table size may become quite large. also, the number of write operations will be high too. does indexing still make sense ?

Comment: Indexing almost always makes sense; partitioning rarely makes sense.  Because of how many variations there are, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` as it currently stands.  (Your description did not include Engine, indexes, `PRIMARY KEY`, datatypes, etc; _all_ _may_ be important to discuss.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "As the timestamp is automatically added by mySQL , one can expect the timestamp column to be sorted"

Without an index the search will require a full table scan, regardless of whether similar values are physically co-located.  That's because there's no way for the database to know that similar timestamp values are co-located.  Besides, disk write optimization techniques are such that we cannot make assumptions about the physical location of any given piece of data,

Probably (depending on your definition of "fairly large") you should consider [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-types.html).  We can define partitions with DATE or TIMESTAMP ranges.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    msg_id INT NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    msg_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(msg_timestamp) ) (
PARTITION pmin VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2014_q1 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2014_q2 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2014_q3 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2014_q4 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2015_q1 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2015_q2 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-07-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2015_q3 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION p2015_q4 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 00:00:00') ),
PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Partitioning is useful because it guarantees the co-location of related timestamps, with the benefit that the database knows about the scheme and so can use it to constrain searches [by partition pruning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-pruning.html).  Basically, if a query is restricted by the columns used for the partition key, the database will only scan partitions which hold those values.  The downside is that queries which don't use the partition key may be slower than they would have been against a non-partitioned table.